# Converting VS2008 Website to Web Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Has anybody ever converted a visual studio website to a web application?  I would like to get sln and vbproj files for my website but I can't seem to find the convert.  I would hate to have to do this by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like what you're looking for:

http://weblogs.asp.net/meligy/archive/2008/08/03/converting-vs-2008-website-to-web-application.aspx

Similar, if not the same as John's suggestion.

Comment: Looks like the link is dead now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good walkthrough just start from step 2.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907624.aspx

OK just tested it

Just create Web Application Project

Copy files in from Website

Right click on project and Convert To Web Application.

Comment: I already know how to go from 2005 to 2008 I need to take a 2008 website and create a web application out of it.  Thanks though.

Comment: Surely you just start from the Creating a Visual Studio 2008 Web Application Project section. Thir first bit is just getting you a 2008 website. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @John I could be wrong but I'm guessing you noticed the small section about testing the website that results from the conversion wizard before converting that to the web app.  The article does run you through the full process of going from 2005 web site to a 2008 website then to a 2008 web application!