# No .csproj file for web application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, csproj

My boss asked me to make changes to a web application which resides in svn. Not much is known about the development of this application as it was done years back.

I did check out the folder and noticed the is a bin folder as well as App_Code with all the associated .aspx and .aspx.cs files as well. What is missing though is the .csproj file.

How do I create one so that I may open it in visual studio and make changes and rebuild accordingly?

Comment: Make an empty project, and drag & drop all files into it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting VS2008 Website to Web Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953138/converting-vs2008-website-to-web-application).

Comment: I suppose what you see is Web site project type. You should be able to open is as Web site through Open menu, just point to directory where file are placed.

Comment: It's a web site "project". They're not actually projects, so they behave strangely. They should be avoided, if only because anyone you talk to will assume you're using a web application project, and you're not, so the answers they give you will be wrong.

Comment: I have this kind of project in my solution and I am not able to build the solution through poweshell script. Is there any way to convert this to .net web app project?